# Binding int to Label in javaFX

Tags: javafx, binding

I'm trying to bind a `int`object to a `Label` in javaFX and i don't want to change the type in the model to a `IntegerProperty`. I tried as

`mainActionLabel.setText(myintvar);`

`mainActionLabel.textProperty().bind(new SimpleIntegerProperty(myintvar.asString());`

but the value only updates if i close and open the gui again, so i guess the bind is not *really* working since i imagine it updating with the setText method.

Is there another way to properly bind it?

Edit: I just tried to remove the

`mainActionLabel.setText(myintvar);`

line but the problem persist as before: the is initialized correctly, but does not update in real time. Only if I close the window and reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unwilling to change the model data to IntegerProperty, you will not be able to take advantage of property bindings.

You will have to implement the synchronization yourself using [listeners](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-) and in the getters and setters of your model.

Comment: You're right, that was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`asString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#asString--) for the `IntegerProperty`:

```
IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
Button btn = new Button("increment");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    property.set(property.get()+1);
});
Label label = new Label();

label.textProperty().bind(property.asString());
```

Comment: You are completely right. But now I am facing another problem.

Comment: Let's say i have my `int` value in another class, and i get this value by the
`player.getPlayerActions().getMainActions()`
method just returns an `int`
Then i do this in my view
`SimpleIntegerProperty usableMA = new SimpleIntegerProperty(player.getPlayerActions().getMainActions());`
   `mainActionLabel.textProperty().bind(usableMA.asString());`

the problem written above persists. Is it because the IntegerProperty is not directly changed when i change the value of the `int` in the other class? Am i missing a piece in the 'observable' pattern, because the `usableMA` is in another class?

Comment: @AndreaCane: If there is just the getter for the `int`, then there is no way of being informed of changes. To update the text you need to get informed of a change in some way. Usually you use a property in the class that contains the int, see e.g. `Bill` class in the following article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm (uses double instead though)

Comment: Yes, i started implementing listeners and now it works.